# How to Clear a model object list

Tags: python, django, xml-parsing

This is a part of my code.

```
dbList = []
for obj in xmlData.iter("object")
    task = TaskViewModel()
    task.id = obj.("pk")
    task.name = obj.find("field[@name='name']").text
    task.parent_task_id = obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text
    dbList.append(task)
```

My problem is it only gives me results that repeat.

my expected result is:

```
dbList = ["dale","Michelle","Fred","Debbie"]
```

but it gives me this result:

```
dbList = ["Debbie","Debbie","Debbie","Debbie"]
```

I think I should clear something.

Hi this is the example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <django-objects version="1.0">
<object model="task.task" pk="31">
<field name="name" type="CharField">Dale</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="32">
<field name="name" type="CharField">Michelle</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="33">
<field name="name" type="CharField">Fred</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="34">
<field name="name" type="CharField">Debbie</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
</django-objects>"
```

I have this class

```
class TaskViewModel():
   id = 0
   name = ""
   parent_task_id = ""
```

so that's why i did this:

```
for obj in xmlData.iter("object")
    task = TaskViewModel()
    task.id = obj.("pk")
    task.name = obj.find("field[@name='name']").text
    task.parent_task_id = obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text
    dbList.append(task)
```

Comment: You should probably add an example xml file.

Comment: Yeah. It would help to see what the source data looks like to help debug this

Comment: Hi guys, I added my xml file

Comment: It just online read the last value but four times

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are using to parse your xml, I used the xml library and managed to get the following:

t.xml is the XML file you posted.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('t.xml') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

dbList = []
for node in tree.iter():
    if node.tag == 'field' and node.attrib.get('name') == 'name':
        dbList.append(node.text)
```

Comment: Yes, I also did this but it still gives me the result: dbList = ["Debbie", "Debbie", "Debbie", "Debbie"]

Comment: That's quite odd. I ran this code with the XML and I'm getting `['Dale', 'Michelle', 'Fred', 'Debbie']`

Comment: I see... Because in my case... I have to append it the dbList.append(task) where in task = TaskViewmodel()... I will edit my question so you would see what i mean